# Can I set Gmail filters from Thunderbird?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, thunderbird

I am in the process of moving all my email filters to Gmail, using their Filter features. Right now, all of my filters are inside Thunderbird and now I have to make each filter again from scratch.

Is there a way to set Gmail filter from Thunderbird? So I don't have to go to Gmail web app each time I need to make a new filter.

PS. I am not sure if Gmail refers to this as to a "filter" or "label". What I need is to automatically move a message meeting certain criteria to its dedicated folder inside Gmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters and labels are related, but different things. You create filters to automatically label(and thereby "move") the message.

There's no way to automatically sync your Thunderbird filters to Gmail web.

Comment: I don't want to sync them. I am looking for a way to create Gmail Filter from within Thunderbird? I could not find a way to do it in Thunderbird, but maybe there is an addon which can do this, and I am not aware of it.

Comment: All the same, it's not possible